# Loop Through a Text File and Split into Multiple Output Files

Tags: python

I am associating an Account number and the name of the output file I would like. I need to search in a text file between account 123456789 and 'thank you for your inquiry' grab that code and write it into an output file called 'Hello.txt'.

I need to loop again and extract the info between '55555-55555' and 'Thank you for your inquiry' and write that to an output file called 'Bye.txt'. When I run this code, nothing is written to my files.

input:

```
Account number: 123456789
Hi,
This is you bill. Please do not forget to include your account number on
your check.
If you have any further questions please feel free to contact me 1-800-325-
3232. Press
option 1 to reach my extension 1234.
Thank you for your inquiry

Account Number: 55555-55555
Hi,
This is you bill. Please do not forget to include your account number on
your check.
If you have any further questions please feel free to contact me 1-800-325-
3232. Press
option 1 to reach my extension 1234.
Thank you for your inquiry
```

My Script:

```
with open('SumBillRpt2019-2-27 Cyl 20.txt') as of:
    for line in of.read().split('\n'):
        for account, new_file in d.items():
            with open(new_file, 'w') as nf:
                if account in line:
                    writing = True
                if writing:
                    nf.write(line)
                    print(nf)
                if 'Thank you for your Inquiry' in line:
                    writing = False
```

Output should be:

hello.txt

```
12345-6789
some lines
Thank you for your inquiry
```

Bye.txt

```
55555-55555
some lines
Thank you for your inquiry
```

Comment: "Can you someone help me fix my code?" Specifically, what's wrong with it? Please read [ask]. Also, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: What does your input file look like? Please [edit] your question and add an example of its contents.

Comment: "What does your input file look like? Please edit your question and add an example of its contents" - Hi @martineau  just edited it

Comment: That's better, but where do the `14046-17100` and `82031-07423` come from that are shown in your two output files? It's also unclear what the account number format is: Is it nine digit characters or 2 groups of 5 digits separated by a dash `-` character?

Comment: @martineau sorry, i was trying to change up with numbers due to discretion. I edited my original post with the correct info. Yes the account number has a dash after 5 digits. I know my logic is right about finding account number until "Thank you for your inquiry". I just dont know how to split it into different files.

Comment: Sorry, even with the last edit, your question still doesn't make sense to me. Among other things, the `123456789` shown as input is not an "account number has a dash after 5 digits". Can there be more than one pair of `Account Number:` groups in the input file and if so, how are they to be handled with respect to the two output files? What is variable `d` in your code snippet? What does your code do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
def to_file(in_file, start_key, end_key, out_file):
    with open(in_file) as fd:
        data = fd.readlines()

    start_index = 0
    while start_index < len(data) and start_key not in data[start_index]:
        start_index += 1

    if start_index == len(data):
        print(" start_key not found")
        return

    with open(out_file, 'w') as fdo:
        curr = start_index
        while curr < len(data) and end_key not in data[curr]:
            fdo.write(data[curr])
            curr += 1

        if end_key == len(data):
            print(" end_key not found")
            return
        fdo.write(data[curr])
```

Another approach would be to use re library instead:

```
def to_file(in_file, start_key, end_key, out_file):
    import re

    with open(in_file) as fd:
        data = fd.read()

    PATTERN = rf'{start_key}.*?{end_key}'

    try:
        result_found = re.findall(PATTERN, data, re.DOTALL)[0]
    except IndexError:
        print("Pattern not found")
        return

    with open(out_file, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(result_found)
```

To call either of the functions above, use something like:

```
to_file('SumBill.txt', '123456789', 'thank you for your inquiry', 'hello.txt')
to_file('SumBill.txt', '55555-55555', 'Thank you for your inquiry', 'bye.txt')
```

Comment: I get an error when running the code above "start_key not found"

Comment: Did you call the function to_file() with the correct start_key? As in are you sure the start_key you used is in in_file? Did you supply the correct in_file? I tried both implementations on the input in your post, and they both work, at least for normal cases.